# Finding the language accepted by a DFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I've got this DFA and I need to figure out and describe the language that it accepts. I figured that $M= \{\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, \{a,b\},1, \{1,5\}, \delta\}$
Now I don't know how to move forward.
[image: DFA]

Comment: This isn't a DFA. It's an NFA. It accepts only two words, which you can surely figure out on your own.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus why is it an NFA? According to my definition it's a DFA but I could be missing something.

Comment: Yes, there are several different definitions. Mine requires each state to have exactly one outgoing edge for every alphabet symbol. Other definitions only require at most one edge.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your point, the DFA you described, according to my definition, is a "complete DFA" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a DFA D, $\ L(D)=\{w \in \Sigma^* | \ \hat{\delta}(q_0,w) \in  F \}$ where $\hat{\delta}(q,w)$ is the extended transition function.

In your case:

$L(M)=\{w \in (a+b)^* | \ \hat{\delta}(1,w) \in  \{1,5\} \}$

In other words your language is the set of all the string such that you can go from the initial state to a final state.

In your case there are just 2 strings for which you can go from State $1$ to a final state.

Comment: would they be: "the empty string" and "ba"?

Comment: The 2 strings both respect the definition, so yes.